# Touchscreen works on Ubuntu 15.10 but not on 14.04 (HP)

Tags: 14.04, touchscreen

First I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my HP pavilion touchscreen laptop and my touch is working properly on that but now on 14.04.

What I have to do for this, in order to make my touchscreen working on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Does upgrading the kernel to 4.2.0-18 in 14.04.3 lts help?

Answer (score 2):

You can install kernel from Ubuntu 15.10 that should support your touchscreen.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

and reboot when installation is finished.

You may need to install Broadcom wireless drivers from 15.10 source. Run

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i  bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
```

Comment: After using, sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily in terminal touch screen is working but my wifi driver is not working which is proprietary  driver.

Comment: Which is that driver and how did you install it? If it is Broadcom, it is not a problem to fix.

Comment: It is a Broadcom 802.11 Linux wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source(proprietary)     But problem remains same wifi driver is not working

Comment: Using additional drivers in software updates it shows that driver.

Comment: I updated the answer. That is a good notice that the default drivers do not install into 4.2.