# Touch screen not working on hp pavilion x360

Tags: touchscreen

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my hp pavilion x360. At the very beginning the touch screen worked (not as good as in MS-Windows but at least worked. I did something probably and now it is not working at all. I have the 4.2.0-34-generic kernel. 
I installed the kubuntu desktop and still have the problem
Please someone help me on how to fix up this

Sorry for my English. I am Spanish speaker

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to install kernel linux-image-generic-lts-utopic

According to the bug report your issue is fixed in it.

But it is not available under your system - you have to install it manually or compile from source.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image-generic-lts-utopic

Other solution is here:
[Touchscreen works on Ubuntu 15.10 but not on 14.04 (HP)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698342/touchscreen-works-on-ubuntu-15-10-but-not-on-14-04-hp)